# move gallery images

Tags: android, gallery

i shows a images in gallery like this

```
             <  Gallery Images  >
```

in above the left arrow(<) and right arrow(>) are also images. in between those images i shows a gallery images. so i want to perform onclick action on that images i.e., the left arrow(<) and right arrow(>). if clicked on the left arrow(<) the gallery images are will be move to left. or if clicked on right arrow(>) the gallery images are will be move to right.

so please tell me your answer.

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i get a position of the view and then define a field

```
 private int mPos = 0;
```

then check the

```
 if (mPos < galleryimages.length - 1)
     ++mPos;
     galleryview.setSelection(mPos, true);
```

this is for right arrow(>) and for left arrow(<) is

```
 if (mPos > 0)
     --mPos;
     galleryview.setSelection(mPos, true);
```

This is the answer and also it is working.